# how to share movie file in ubuntu one file (Share With Me)?

Tags: share

how to share movie file in ubuntu one file (Share With Me?) and how my friend get my movie file in ubuntu one (Share With Me) ?

Answer (score 0):

The person you are trying to share the file with has to have his pc synced to your Ubuntu-One account and than you would just add the file to the shared with me folder on your desktop and he will see it in his shared with me folder on the other side. I think that's what your asking?

Or you could just add the file to one of your Ubuntu-One folder and just share it and send him the link. Either method will fetch the results you are looking for.